# How does grunt uncss task work internally

Tags: javascript, css, gruntjs, uncss, gulp-uncss

I have written grunt uncss task to remove the unused css in my code. But its removing a lot of css which is being used in my code.
I guess the reason is, its not checking for css inside the directive `'my-directive'`
Here is my index.html:

```
<div> 
  <span class="duplicate-text" ng-if="duplicateMode" ng-bind-template="{{'html.peopleeditor.duplicate.label'|property}}"></span>
</div>
<div class="peopleeditor col-xs-10 col-sm-10 col-md-10 col-lg-10" id="peopleeditorcontainer">
  <my-directive controller="actionframework.controller" options="options"/>
</div>
```

Inside my index.css, i have some classes like:

```
.peopleeditor .form-horizontal .control-label,
    .peopleeditor .form-horizontal .radio,
    .peopleeditor .form-horizontal .checkbox,
    .peopleeditor .form-horizontal .radio-inline,
    .peopleeditor .form-horizontal .checkbox-inline {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-top: 0;
    }
.duplicate-text {
  font-family: 'Roboto-Bold', sans-serif;
  font-size: 12px;
}
```

On running grunt uncss task, many of the styles with .peopleeditor class is being removed. Is it because `peopleeditor` classes will be applied to html tags inside `'my-directive'`. Is there any way to read the styling inside directive templates, so that grunt uncss task does not ignore this.

Comment: You can specify what files/directory's grunt uncss should use to see if they are unused: https://github.com/addyosmani/grunt-uncss#usage-examples

Answer (score 2):

There is an `ignore` option where you can add `class`es and `id`s added at runtime, like your directive classes.

```
ignore (Array): provide a list of selectors that should not be removed by UnCSS. For example, styles added by user interaction with the page (hover, click), since those are not detectable by UnCSS yet. Both literal names and regex patterns are recognized. Otherwise, you can add a comment before specific selectors:

/* uncss:ignore */
.selector1 {
    /* this rule will be ignored */
}

.selector2 {
    /* this will NOT be ignored */
}

/* uncss:ignore start */

/* all rules in here will be ignored */

/* uncss:ignore end */
```

There's also an option, `ignoreSheets`, to ignore entire stylesheets if necessary.

View the [UnCSS docs](https://github.com/giakki/uncss) for more info.

Based on your current `Gruntfile.js` you'll want to add it like this:

```
module.exports = function(grunt) {

   grunt.initConfig({
      pkg: grunt.file.readJSON('package.json'),

      uncss:{
         dist: {
             files:{
                 'dist/index.css' : ['apps/**/*.*']
             },
             options: {
               ignore: ['.peopleeditor'] // Add classes, or regex
             }
        }
      }
   });
   grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-uncss');

   grunt.registerTask('default', [
      'uncss:dist'
   ]);
};
```

Comment: Here is my github repo, where i have added grunt-uncss task: https://github.com/jasmeen10/Grunt-project 
I do not see an option to ignore the list of selectors which should not be removed, as there are quiet a lot of them.

Comment: I've updated the solution with a potential fix for your current `Gruntfile.js`

Comment: Thanks for the solution. 
But I was just assuming, the classes inside directive must be well considered by grunt task (as these are not styles added by user interaction). Since it is considering some of the styling with .peopleeditor class and removing some, so it felt like i am doing something incorrect.

Comment: Nope. you're not doing anything wrong. The classes are being added via JS. A better solution might be to prefix all the classes added in Angular with `js-` or something similar. Then you can use a regex in the `ignore` option to ignore any classes starting with `js-`.